# C# Oracle table issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle

I've got a problem with my ASP.NET application when I'm trying to log in a user. The issue is that when I'm  trying to run the query, an exception gets thrown which says the tale name is invalid. It's because the table is called USER, which is a part of SQL.

I'm not in a position where I can change the table name.

```
        public bool LoginUser(string username, string password)
    { 
        //Database Connectie maken
        DBConnectionOpen();

        string query = @"SELECT NICKNAME, PASSWORD FROM " + "'USER'" + "WHERE NICKNAME = '" + username + "'";
        bool result = false;

        try
        {
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            Console.WriteLine("*Query Uitvoeren*");
            reader.Read();

            if (username + password == reader.GetString(0) + reader.GetString(1))
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return result;    


    }
```

Comment: As you noted, USER is part of SQL, therefore you cannot use it as the name of your table. Would be like trying to name your table with another reserved word "STRING". It's going to fail. You'll have to rename your table. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the response, but I finally figured it out.

What the query should have been:

```
        string query = @"SELECT NICKNAME, ""PASSWORD"" FROM ""USER"" WHERE NICKNAME = '" + username + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Whomever named the table "USER" should have db privs removed, but I think you just need to add double quotes around the table name:

```
select * from "USER" where ...
```

Note that its case sensitive when you add the double quotes, so if the table is named User you'd need "User" instead of "USER"

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct your SQL statement like the following:

string query = "SELECT NICKNAME, PASSWORD FROM [USER] WHERE NICKNAME = '" + username + "'";

Also, if you are using SQL reserved word (e.g. `DATE`) as a Column name, then enclose it in angular brackets (like `[DATE]`) in your SQL statement.

Hope this may help.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately, still the same error.

Comment: See the corrected version of your SQL string in my answer. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You are querying on the string value 'USER'.
You should use

```
string query = @"SELECT NICKNAME, PASSWORD FROM [USER] WHERE NICKNAME = '" + username + "'";
```

This will query on the table called USER. In SQL normally you use brackets to indicate you are querying on an object if what you mean can be ambiguous.

The concatenation of the table name as a string is unnecessary so I left it out. If you change it to a variable it can be useful.

In addition instead of concatenating username maybe you should also use alternative for Oracle what is called SqlParameter for SQL Server, to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll check it out. And I'll add the sqlParameters later.

Comment: Try to execute the query in a client database tool, like Toad or whatever. Normally with SQL Server you should try the query in SQL Server Management Studio.